# Authentication provider for specific REST resource only

Tags: 9, authentication-authorization

I would like to use my own auth provider for my REST services. While there's no fundamental problem with creating it, adding to my `services.yml` and referencing it in the `.yml` of the resource, it is called for each route, not just my resources, as logging reveals. Yes, I can inject a `RouteMatchInterface` into my auth provider and use the `applies()` function to check whether the provider should be consulted on a specific route but why is this required?

Can't I limit my provider to only the resource I plan to use it with? Using `applies()` not only means extra overhead on each call, it makes it awkward to maintain, needing to modify usage in both places, the config files *and* the auth provider source code.

Comment: Well, the comments in `AuthenticationProviderFilterInterface` do suggest a probable cause, so this might be the sad truth after all...

Comment: Yes, applying an authentication provider and checking the route requirements are two different things happening at different times.

Comment: But then, what's the point of checking what auth is supported for a given resource, if all will be called, anyway?

Comment: Normally applies() should not contain time consuming code, it just checks for credentials provided in the request. If someone provides credentials for a REST service, but calls a non-API URL, Drupal will respond with a 403.

Comment: That's what one of my provider's ˙applies()` does. But the second one would need to provide anonymous access (no CSRF token or cookie or anything similar required at all). I have nothing to check for in that `applies()` and returning `TRUE` clearly breaks the whole site. That's why it's a trouble I can't force this provider to only apply to a single, specific route.

Comment: In theory you can authenticate against anything in the request, also the path.

Comment: I think I'll have to go with that (although this still makes it two places where I need to maintain the URL). Another idea was to use a dummy query variable just in these calls but that feels even less elegant. :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is part of an ongoing, older problem. For instance, Drupal forces CSRF checks on non-GET resources automatically, even is the `cookie` provider is not used for a resource. This is part of the same problem, nothing actually enforces that only the providers you specify are actually used. (And, what's worse, it doesn't look like removing the `_csrf_request_header_token` requirement on the route does anything about it.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into a related issue.
In my case, using the `applies()` method in my custom provider makes sense.

What's bothering me is it's behaviour.
When `applies()` returns `FALSE`, it goes directly to the **REST resource plugin** and (for example) will execute my **PATCH request**. After what it goes to the `authenticate()` method of the provider.

I don't understand this logic, as it seems to me that the authenticate should be validated before executing the **REST request**.
So we don't process a request for nothing in case of failed authentication.

Any thoughts ?